# Flutter persisting fingerprint

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter

Is there a way in flutter to register multiple fingerprint and persist that data in order to re-use it in other devices?

I've try with local_auth, but it does not meet the requirement that I am needing.

```
LocalAuthentication auth = LocalAuthentication();
List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics = await auth.getAvailableBiometrics();
availableBiometrics.forEach((x) => print(x.toString()));
bool didAuthenticate = await auth.authenticateWithBiometrics(localizedReason: 'Please authenticate');
```

Comment: On iOS devices (and I presume on Android devices) you have no access to the actual biometric data; it is stored in the secure element that even the operating system cannot access. The authentication process simply returns a true/false indicating whether a biometric credential was matched. If multiple fingerprints are enrolled on a device there is no detail about which fingerprint was matched. Remember, also, that newer iOS devices don't have fingerprint readers. They use FaceID, but the local authentication framework still works.

Comment: I have same requirement, could you please help me what you have used for reading fingerprint data

Comment: I have done this far back and have done for whole 10 fingers, will create Blog for same and upload it